# Правка стиля для ссылки

Tags: php, html

Всем привет

```
// внутри php цикла
echo "<a href=\"index.php?pagw=".$pagw."\">".$pagw."</a>";

// на выходе, код выглядит:
<a href="index.php?pagw=1">1</a><a href="index.php?pagw=2">2</a><a href="index.php?pagw=3">3</a>
```

По логике вещей, все это добро должно выводиться в строчку, а в моем случае - каждая ссылка в новой строчке. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте, попробую помочь. Первое, что приходит в голову, то что проблема в css. Возможно где-то фиксированная длина стоит, или что-то этого роде

Comment: выяснил. в свойстве у "a" прописано

    display: block; // является жизненно необходимым

а как сделать, что бы там где мне нужно, стиль у "a", конкретно в данном коде изменить? т.е. стиль для "а" применяется еще много где, и охота переправить только в данном коде

Comment: Можно в css создать class для определенных ссылок. Пример 
`a.url{ display: block; }`. Ко всем где надо блочные ссылки дописывайте атрибут class='url'

Comment: понял (придется переправлять оч. много где). а наоборот можно? что бы все ссылки остались как есть, а конкретно этой сделать, что бы у нее этого свойства не было?

Comment: Попробуйте тогда, именно к этим ссылкам прописать  display: inline; . Вы поняли куда надо? Или расписать?

Comment: Удачи Вам!

Answer (score 0):

Так это не в PHP дело, дело в верстке - в какой контейнер ты эти ссылки добавляешь(div, span, ul, tr...) и какие стили навешаны на контейнер и на сами ссылки.
[Вот посмотрите, например](http://ab-w.net/CSS/css_lists.php)